# Is there an easy way to have dynamic/ExpandoObject return strings and not objects?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I want to use a dynamic object where I'd normally use `Dictionary<string, string>`.
I want to go from

```
dict.Add("key", "value");
string val = dict["key"];
```

to

```
 dyna.key = "value";
 string val = dyna.key
```

Typical `ExpandoObject` will return an `object` for `dyna.key`, what's an easy way to make it return strings without casting when accessing each value?

---

EDIT: I'm sorry, I haven't dug enough into my problem --

It's not that the code I'm calling can't use it as a string, it has THIS:

```
public static implicit operator SomethingSomething(string name)
```

That's why it breaks

EDIT2: welp, I'm an idiot, only after recreating it from scratch did I read the full error message: has no applicable method named 'GetMyClass' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: Your "to" example *already shows this*... there's no cast ;p

Comment: Why can't you simply use a "normal" non-dynamic object?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: Are you using these features "just because they're there"? I agree with @Jordell - why not just using `Dictionary<String,String>`

Comment: why not dictionary - I want to avoid the brackets and the quotes... make code shorter

Comment: If the objects are always Strings why do you see the need to go to a dynamic object ?

Comment: @user957902, if you know of a way to use a non dynamic object with that syntax (without quotes for keys, or brackets for accessing members) -- that's exactly what I want

Comment: @Madd0g: You could write your own class, no? Don't go dynamic if you don't need it just because the syntax is nicer. Use dictionary or roll a class if you don't want to use an indexer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Typical ExpandoObject will return an object for dyna.key

Erm, not exactly, it will return whatever you tell it to return:

```
dynamic dyna = new ExpandoObject();
dyna.key = "value";
string val = dyna.key;
```

of course you can no longer rely on compile time checking and the following code will obviously crash at runtime:

```
dynamic dyna = new ExpandoObject();
dyna.key = "value";
int val = dyna.key;
```

So make sure that you are using the same type as the one used to store the value.

---

UPDATE:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        dynamic dyna = new ExpandoObject();
        dyna.key = "value";
        Test(dyna.key);
    }

    public static void Test(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE 2:

I still don't see what the problem is:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
        d.key = "value";
        Program p = d.key;
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator Program(string name)
    {
        return new Program
        {
            Name = name
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to pass them directly to methods expecting string, that doesn't work if I'm not using a variable, right?

Comment: @Madd0g, and what's the problem with that? Are you having some specific issues? See my update. This will simply work. It's just that the type resolution happens at runtime.

Comment: @Madd0g: Why don't you just *test it yourself*??

Comment: @Madd0g do you mean as an argument? well, that depends: are you happy for the method's resolution to happen at runtime? If you *are*, then don't worry: it'll already just work. If you want the method resolution to happen at compile-time, you *must* add a cast. `dynamic` is infectious: if you don't get rid of the `dynamic` by casting (one way or another), then the expression it is *used in* becomes `dynamic`.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I was testing it on my own, I just hadn't realized what I'm seeing - please see update on the OP

Comment: @Madd0g, I still don't see what the problem is. Please see my UPDATE 2. So are you willing to ask a real question, by telling us what your actual problem is in an easily reproducible code snippet, the way I post my answers?

Comment: Visual studio marks the method call red when I try to call that method with the dynamic member, it works perfectly with a literal string, I seriously don't understand what I'm doing differently :( I'll dig more I guess

Comment: Sorry Darin, I hadn't noticed it was an extension method, apparently extension methods can't work with dynamic objects.

Comment: @Madd0g: You need to call the extension method as the static method it really is. So for example `x.ToList()` becomes `Enumerable.ToList(x)`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, right, I see that, but the static class name is 35 characters long - I fear that in my quest to code beauty that is not a step forward :)

Comment: @Madd0g, yes extension methods cannot be dispatched on dynamic types. It is simply a feature that the language doesn't support.

Answer (score 2):

With `dynamic`, all casts are implicit, so:

```
dynamic key = ...
dyna.key = "value";
string val = dyna.key;
```

already does the job.

More accurately, the member-access (`.key`) returns `dynamic`, and this `dynamic` result has an implicit cast (a type-check, verified at runtime) to the target-type, `string`.